# How to view page builder widgets when running local preview with Stencil CLI

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am new to Stencil and Big Commerce, and I am working to make some changes for a friend's site. Most of their front page elements were made with widgets on the page builder.

When I run Stencil CLI to pull a copy of the current them and run it locally, I see the basic theme of the site and the "New Products" category that is hard coded into the theme template, but none of his added widgets appear in this local preview.

Is it possible to pull/import these widgets so I can style & preview them without hard coding them into the template or having to push updates to the live server to preview changes made to styling?
Or is it a best practice to delete all his widgets and just hard code them into the the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible via BigCommerce, we are looking at supporting this in the future though.

---

**UPDATE:** This is now supported

Check out the changelog in the developer center for more info!
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog#publications/published-widgets-now-appear-during-local-development-with-stencil-cli

Comment: Thank you, Heather. So would it be a best practice to hard code these elements into the template then?

Comment: You can view widget templates and widgets on the live store, you can create them via api and either place them using page builder or placement api. This will be on the live store though. You can definitely still use widgets, once a widget template has been created, it is available in the widget section of page builder for you to see & apply.

Comment: Hi @IB21, I just updated the above answer -- check out this new update in our changelog https://developer.bigcommerce.com/changelog#publications/published-widgets-now-appear-during-local-development-with-stencil-cli :)

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I'm updating and testing now!